# How can I get the values after colons in a single string using regex

Tags: javascript

I have this string:

```
var str = "current_year:45;last_year:20;all:65";
```

I would like to have this result using regex or split:

```
var a = ["current_year", "last_year", "all"]
var b = ["45", "20", "65"]
```

I have already tried to use this:  `/([^:\s]+):([^:\s]+)/g`, but it didn't work well

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Why regex? This seems easy enough to do with splits.

Comment: It can be also split

Comment: What was the result when you tried to use `split()`?

Comment: That doesn't really say how you used that regex. In any case, consider the quote "I had a problem, so I decided to use regex. Now, I have two problems." :). Work on a solution around `split()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to use `split` here. If you want regex solution then you can do as:

```js
var str = "current_year:45;last_year:20;all:65";

const [a, b] = str.match(/[^;]+/g).reduce(
  (acc, curr) => {
    const [first, second] = curr.match(/[^:]+/g);
    acc[0].push(first);
    acc[1].push(second);
    return acc;
  },
  [[], []]
);
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output full height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**2)** Using match, map and forEach

```js
var str = "current_year:45;last_year:20;all:65";

const a = [];
const b = [];

str.match(/[^;]+/g).forEach((s) => {
  const [first, second] = s.match(/[^:]+/g);
  a.push(first);
  b.push(second);
});

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output full height. So IGNORE IT */

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

**3)** Using replace only

```js
var str = "current_year:45;last_year:20;all:65";

const a = [];
const b = [];

str.replace(/[^;]+/g, (m) => {
  const [first, second] = m.match(/[^:]+/g);
  a.push(first);
  b.push(second);
  return "";
});

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output full height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: You can also use `/[^;]+/g` here

Comment: @More simplified solution added. Have a look

Answer (score 1):

Starting with
`current_year:45;last_year:20;all:65`

If you split on `;` and then split each result on `:`, you'll get:

```
[ 
  [ 'current_year', '45' ],
  [ 'last_year', '20' ],
  [ 'all', '65' ]
]
```

Then you can either map it to two separate arrays, or to an object.

**As two arrays:**

```
[ 'current_year', 'last_year', 'all' ]
[ '45', '20', '65' ]
```

**As an object:**

```
{ current_year: '45', last_year: '20', all: '65' }
```

Using this code:

```js
const str = "current_year:45;last_year:20;all:65";

// Useful intermediate format
const temp = str.split(';').map(s => s.split(':'));

// As two arrays: (a) keys, and (b) values
const a = temp.map(v => v[0]);
const b = temp.map(v => v[1]);
console.log(a, b);

// Or as an object
var obj = Object.fromEntries(temp);
console.dir(obj);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer !!